# Batch File (.bat) Equivalent of Shell Script (.sh) "&!"

Tags: python, windows, shell, batch-file

I have a problem trying to achieve the same goal on a Windows machine VS. a Linux machine. The issue is that I have a python script that calls a batch/shell script depending on the current OS and the batch script won't allow the calling python script to continue.

Here is how the python code calls the scripts:

```py
# Windows
subprocess.call([os.path.join(os.getcwd(), r'Data/restart.bat')])
# Linux
subprocess.call([r'./Data/restart.sh'])
```

When the shell script is called, I can only assume it starts its own process and allows the calling python script to continue:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Restarting..."
sleep 5
python3.8 main.py &!
```

When the batch script is called, it keeps the python script running when it needs to continue:

```
echo Restarting...
timeout /t 5
start /b py main.py
```

So my question is how would I achieve the same results as the shell script for my batch file, whether that be through modifying the batch file or changing how it's called in python?

Comment: Maybe running the restart script as a background process with `start`?

Comment: @dan1st I believe that's what I've done unless I'm missing something. Could the "/b" be causing the issue? I have it there so that I can keep the same window in case I need to backtrace an error.

Comment: Try adding a title argument immediately following the `start` — i.e `start "sometitle" /b py main.py`. Although it's documented as an optional argument, in my experience it's best to always have it.

Comment: @VoidTwo - Yes, the /B option will interfere. I think you should be able to launch the script directly from Python asynchronously without a window, but I don't know the syntax.